# Oracle with join , need uniques

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Hi i have a "small" problem , iam using join to get some names for OS Architectures.

```
SELECT "OSARCH".,   "OS". FROM "OSARCH"
 INNER JOIN "OS" ON OSARCH.OSARCH_ID = OS.OSARCH_ID
```

The result is something like this :

```
OSARCH_ID OSARCH
--        -------
22        Powerpc
22        Powerpc
22        Powerpc
28        x86
28        x86
28        x86
21        x80
21        x80
```

is there any elegant way to get an result with uniques ?

```
OSARCH_ID OSARCH
--------  ------
22        Powerpc
28        x86
21        x80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT osarch_id, osarch
FROM ....
```